# Clues needed for joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join

This seems as if it should be easy but I haven't managed to create the proper query or to find an equivalent situation. Let's say I have 3 tables that I'd like to join: `Artist`, `Album`, and `Track`. (Actually I don't have these tables but the tables I'm working with have equivalent relationships.)

Each `artist` can have many `album`s and each `album` can have many `track`s.

The `artist` table is indexed on `artist_id` and contains information about the artist (`name`, `address`, `phone number`, and such).

The `album` table is indexed on `artist_id` and `album_id`. It contains the name of the album and other information (`recording date`, `location`, etc).

The `track` table is indexed on `artist_id`, `album_id`, and `track_nbr`. It contains the name of the track, length, and such.

What I'm trying to do is create a report that would look like this:

```
Artist|Album|Track#|Track Name
The Wizard of Frobozz|Zork I|01|The White House
The Wizard of Frobozz|Zork I|02|Eaten by a Grue
The Wizard of Frobozz|Zork I|03|Take the Sword
The Wizard of Frobozz|Zork I|04|Don't Forget the Lantern
The Wizard of Frobozz|Zork II|01|Waiting for the Volcano Gnome
The Wizard of Frobozz|Zork II|02|On the Left Bank of Zork
The Wizard of Frobozz|Zork II|03|In the Oddly Angled Room
```

I can join the `artist` and `album` tables to get all of the `albums` but when I add the `track` table, I get only one `track` per `album`-`artist` combination.

This seems like it should work but doesn't:

```
select a.name, l.album, t.track_nbr, t.track_name
from track t, album l, artist a 
where t.artist_id = l.artist_id
and l.artist_id = a.artist_id
and t.album_id = a.album_id
order by a.name, l.album, t.track_nbr;
```

My guess is that I need to explicitly declare a join and possibly add parentheses to group the joins but I haven't been able to find documentation that I can fully comprehend to do this.

So ... Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT a.name, l.album, t.track_nbr, t.track_name
 FROM artist a
 LEFT JOIN album l ON a.artist_id = l.artist_id
 LEFT JOIN track t ON t.album_id = a.album_id
 ORDER BY a.name, l.album, t.track_nbr;
```

**Database design-related question**: Why do you have `artist_id` in the `track` table? The `artist_id` is already defined through the `album` that this track belongs to.

Comment: Thanks. And point taken on the unnecessary inclusion of artist_id in the tracks table.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.name,
    l.album,
    t.track_nbr,
    t.track_name
from track t
inner join album l on t.album_id = l.album_id
inner join artist a on l.artist_id = a.artist_id
order by a.name,
    l.album,
    t.track_nbr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this:

```
and t.album_id = a.album_id
```

Actually be this?

```
and t.album_id = l.album_id
```

Also, I believe that third WHERE clause is more than you actually need. I think this does the trick:

```
select a.name, l.album, t.track_nbr, t.track_name
from track t, album l, artist a 
where t.album_id = l.album_id
and l.artist_id = a.artist_id
order by a.name, l.album, t.track_nbr;
```

What exactly do you mean when you say that the album table is indexed on album_id and artist_id? Are you including `artist_id` in the primary key of the `album` table? This is superfluous, as you already have a unique value in `album_id`.